# Make Woocommerce Product Subcategory small boxes without image

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I work on small home project, and removed images from category/subcategory to be shown into shop page. I corrected blocks to be small, into [shop page](https://micromedico.com/shop/), but when go to category that have subcategory inside blocks are much larger then others.. So i want all blocks to be the same size. For example into **shop page**:

[image]

and into **[subcategory page](https://micromedico.com/product-category/areola/)**:

[image]

i tryed to fix that blocs via this CSS:

```
.fusion-blog-layout-grid .post .fusion-post-wrapper, .fusion-blog-layout-timeline .post, .fusion-portfolio.fusion-portfolio-boxed .fusion-portfolio-content-wrapper, .products li.product {
height:120px;
}
```

but makes all blocks smaller including products. So any tip how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your style css with follows -

```
.fusion-blog-layout-grid .post .fusion-post-wrapper, .fusion-blog-layout-timeline .post, .fusion-portfolio.fusion-portfolio-boxed .fusion-portfolio-content-wrapper, .products li.product-category.product {
height:120px;
}
```